# Add newline to center length position of text file lines

Tags: php

**input.txt**

```
just some example text, just some example text
some example text
example text, just some example text
```

```
$inFile  = "input.txt";    
$outFile = "output.txt";


$data = array();

$ftm = fopen($outFile, "w+");
$fh = fopen($inFile, "r");      

$data = file($inFile);
foreach ($data as $key => $value)
{
    $row = $value;
    $str_length = strlen($row);

    if ($str_length > 10)
    {
        $width = strlen($row)/2;
        $wrapped = wordwrap($row, $width);

        fwrite($ftm, $wrapped);
    }
    else
    {
        fwrite($ftm, $row);
    }
}
fclose($fh);
```

How can I add a newline **\n** to the center position of each line?

```
//Related:
$wrapped = wordwrap($row, $width, '\N');
```

Comment: you mean use `\n` to word wrap? `$wrapped = wordwrap($row, $width, "\n");`

Comment: @bansi I actually want the "\n" printed inside the string.

Comment: I think that is what `wordwrap` does. I think you never tested your code. it does exactly what you say you want.

Comment: @bansi For some reason it doesn't print if it's lower case.

Comment: You want a literal ``\`` and `n` to be output in your wrapped text? Then `'\n'` on the wordwrap call, `'` strings don't honor backslashed characters the way `"`-quoted strings.

Comment: You can try adding `$newline = '\n';` after `$width = strlen($row)/2;` then `fwrite($ftm, $wrapped . $newline);` @rrrfusco which will write `\n` but only at the very end; if that's what you're asking.

Comment: `if ($str_length > "10")` should be `if ($str_length > 10)` dont do string comparison when numeric comparison is needed.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I actually want to get rid of the trailing \n also

Comment: I misunderstood your question then. If you want lines to be written with no spaces at the end, then in my answer below, replace the `'\n'` with `"\n"` @rrrfusco EDIT: Which I did just now. Details are in my answer. I would need you show edit your question with the intended output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're expecting, but it works given supplied text:

```
just some example text
some example text
example text
```

which results to a written file as: (if using `'\n'`)

```
just some\nexample\ntext
some\nexample\ntext
example\ntext
```

(**EDIT**) and as:

```
just some
example
text
some
example
text
example
text
```

(if using `"\n"`) which will result having no spaces at the end of each line.

PHP

```
<?php
$inFile  = "input.txt";    
$outFile = "output.txt";

$data = array();

$ftm = fopen($outFile, "w+");
$fh = fopen($inFile, "r");      

$data = file($inFile);
foreach ($data as $key => $value)
{

$newline = "\n"; // writes to file with no spaces at the end of each line
// $newline = '\n'; // use single quotes if wanting to write \n in the file

    $row = $value;
    $str_length = strlen($row);

    if ($str_length > 10)
    {

        $width = strlen($row) / 2;
        $wrapped = wordwrap($row, $width, $newline);

        fwrite($ftm, $wrapped);
    }
    else
    {
        fwrite($ftm, $row);

    }
}
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: This is pretty close. When I use "\n" it results in "someexample text" for some reason. ie: no newline is printed. And the whitespace where the newline should be printed is missing.

Comment: Open up the file itself afterwards. On my end, there are seperate lines. I will edit my answer with the output "in file" that I get. @rrrfusco

Comment: See under my **(EDIT) and as:...** @rrrfusco that is what I have in the file itself.

Comment: If the example is word wrapped in notepad++ first, there seems to be 1 whitespace at EOL. When I run this code it adds \N to the end of lines. I've tried rtrim to try and remove it, but that doesn't work. Any thoughts on how to get rid of the trailing \N. Again the center \N should remain.

Comment: I can't see how it would "add" an `\n` in your file. If you're using `'\n'` instead of `"\n"` yes, that will add `\n` in your file. @rrrfusco